# DjangoのModelでchoicesでなおかつ任意の値を入れる場合

Tags: python, django

Django 1.6のModelを使ってます。
複数選択でなおかつ、任意の値を入れたいです。

公式ドキュメントから拝借しましたが、
choicesを使えば以下のように複数選択できます

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (u'M', u'Male'),
        (u'F', u'Female'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

しかし、これだとMとF以外にも「u'未回答'」みたいなのをユーザ側で入れたいときに
入力ができません。
これを実現するには、やはりテンプレート側をカスタマイズするしかないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`default=None`（または、u'未回答')にしちゃいば、いくのでは？

```
gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, 
                          default=u'未回答',
                          choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

あと、`u'未回答'`は、`gender`入力可能な値であれば、`GENDER_CHOICES`に入れるべきですね。

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (u'M', u'Male'),
    (u'F', u'Female'),
    (u'N', u'未回答'),
)
```

Comment: 回答有難う御座います。
しかし、そういう意味ではありません。
例が悪かったですが、任意の文字をユーザにも入力させてもらえるようにしたいということです。

例では性別なのでせいぜい3つかもしれませんが、苗字の方が例としていいかもしれません。

    NAME_CHOICES = (
        (u'Yamada', u'山田'),
        (u'Tanaka', u'田中'),
    )

のときにそれ以外の任意の苗字をいれたいときです。

Comment: なるほど。たぶん`choices`使えないかなと思います。　FormやModelの`.clean()`メッソドで設定されている`choices`にあっているかどうかの確認が行われるじゃないか。すみません、確認していないのですが。

Answer (score 0):

「複数選択でなおかつ、任意の値を入れたい」という要望（いわゆるコンボボックス）は、datalistタグをサポートしているWebブラウザ上であれば、datalistタグを使用することで実現できます。

しかし、datalistタグ自体はDjango1.6ではサポートしていない（現行最新の1.10も同様）ので、カスタムウィジェットやテンプレートで対応する必要があります。
本家Stackoverflowで [カスタムウィジェットを定義して実現している回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32791625/1885815) がありましたので、参考にしてみてください。
この場合、ModelはDBに任意の値を保存する必要があるので、`django.db.models.CharField` に `choices` パラメータを渡す必要はありません。

残念ながら、 [2017/3現在はSafariがdatalistタグをサポートしていない](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) ようですので、Safariをサポートする場合はJavaScriptで実現する必要があります。
[awesomeplate](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/) などの採用を検討してみてください。